# web3js baseFeePerGas 0x7 not number

Tags: javascript, web3js

I want baseFeePerGas to be Number but i get 0x7

here is the code

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

function getBlock() {
          const block = window.web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
          return block
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);
              return data;
            })
            .catch();
        }
```

in data object, i can see

```
author: "0x03801efb0efe2a25ede5dd3a003ae880c0292e4d"
baseFeePerGas: "0x7"
difficulty: "340282366920938463463374607431768211454"
extraData: "0xdb830303038c4f70656e457468657265756d86312e34372e30826c69"
gasLimit: 30000000
gasUsed: 605497
hash: "0x056a0e1c79f1e628bdd63c9485e0cbc24d53e175f37ea0413f827cfe0ddbaae3"
logsBloom: "0x00000000080000000000004000000000000000000000001000200000000000006000000000000000000000004000000000080000000000000000000000040000000040000001000082000008000000000000100000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000010000000000010000000000000000000000000000008000080000800000000000000000000000000004000000000000100000001000000000000100000000008000000040000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000400000100080000000000040000020000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000800000000800000000"
miner: "0x03801EfB0EFe2a25ede5Dd3a003Ae880C0292e4d"
number: 32985524
parentHash: "0xcf86c8c8baf50d0144a6e33dbd6e3154b24a852da9ecadade387b2c620177c95"
receiptsRoot: "0x00ec35b52fddfcbd313f8e041327ab5c61fe40a8ab22e79d5d3f7c47d9b25089"
sealFields: (2) ['0x8418b8d64b', '0xb8418beb9df328272175500bda068d5eabb8645673df1b74…6cc1da08b1f60a2f8fc1da94dc5586f47d12db24da8a30500']
sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347"
signature: "8beb9df328272175500bda068d5eabb8645673df1b740a0bc817197a6c61cd0b212e3da7bb6ecfbc06cc1da08b1f60a2f8fc1da94dc5586f47d12db24da8a30500"
size: 5923
stateRoot: "0xe1c293f770dd96fd48a6bdad2f46df82a3998bedfba82fb5f934f5fee43ddd4c"
step: "414766667"
timestamp: 1659066668
totalDifficulty: "11173949063057428792208919046000090832875997482"
transactions: (3) ['0x186aff88456cd90c4ea72d337407ec52aa43ea931100162eff8137b36fe3d3db', '0x0f01e4fd49e5a15969fa0a1cdf86de6ded0043d4bf0e13d1f86e9f0b80073564', '0xbd2684f6e90fba60296d3ed63a56d0d6926cf81973c6e4b2485e6646a577c9a0']
transactionsRoot: "0x59b9bbce756e9f67fe54500a0be44ea3c73f20d75d0f913af34b307d65ffb129"
```

in the web3js official docs, it says baseFeePerGas is Number, but why am I getting 0x7?

I think it's hex or something else; I want it to be number I need to calculate from it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `baseFeePerGas: "0x7"` is hexadecimal.

You can convert the HEX value like this:

```js
let baseFeePerGasWei = parseInt("0x7", 16);
console.log(baseFeePerGasWei);
```